# To get the number of opportunities in an Account

Tags: salesforce, apex

how to count number of opportunities related to account,

total number of opportunities field on account should be increment/decrement when Opportunity is created/deleted.

How to solve it, pl help me with sample code.

Comment: Did you already try to implement something? Do you need it in Apex or formula fields or etc?

Comment: i want to write a trigger for it

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need write a code if you need count of all opportunities related to an account. Create a “Rollup/Summary” field type on the Account.  Evaluate the Opportunity object, and run a “Count” operation.  That’s it!

**UPD:**
If you need to solve it with trigger it will looks something like this:

```
trigger CountOpportunitiesOnAccount on Opportunity (after insert, after delete){
    Set<Id> aId = new Set<Id>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isDelete || Trigger.isUndelete){
        for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
            aId.add(opp.AccountId);
        }
        updateAccounts(aId);
    }

    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.old){
            aId.add(opp.AccountId);
        }
        updateAccounts(aId);
    }

    private void updateAccounts(Set<Id> accIds){
        List<Account> accs = [select id, OpportunitiesAmount from Account where Id in :accIds];
        List<Opportunity> opps = [select id from Opportunity where AccountId in :accIds];
        for(Account a : accs){
            a.OpportunitiesAmount = opps.size();
        }
        update accs;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to write a trigger

Comment: Why you can't use roll up? You can solve it with Apex trigger but usual formula- and roll-up fields are preferable to code.

Comment: @LastKhajiit it tends to be a lost cause answering questions about Salesforce here, this answer will most likely never be up voted or accepted.

Answer (score 1):

So, here you go. This is the Exact code that counts the Exact number of Related Opportunities of an Account and Populates it on the Standard field of Account Number ( you can add it on the custom field also).

```
trigger TriggTask on Opportunity (after insert, after delete) 
{
List<id> TriggerList = new List<id>();
if(Trigger.isInsert)
{
    List<id> TriggerList = new List<id>();
    for(Opportunity Opp : Trigger.new)
    {
        TriggerList.add(Opp.AccountId);
    }
    List<Account> DML = New List<Account>();
    List<Account> Ls = [select id,(select id from Opportunities) from Account where id in:TriggerList];  

    for(Account AccNew : ls)
    {
        Integer Num = AccNew.Opportunities.size();
        AccNew.AccountNumber=String.valueOf(Num);
        DML.add(AccNew);
    }
    update ls;
}

if(Trigger.isDelete)
{
    for(Opportunity Opp : Trigger.old)
    {
        TriggerList.add(Opp.AccountId);
    }

    List<Account> DML = New List<Account>();
    List<Account> Ls = [select id,(select id from Opportunities) from Account where id in:TriggerList];
    for(Account act : Ls)
    {
        act.AccountNumber=String.valueOf(act.Opportunities.size());
        DML.add(act);
    }
    update Ls;
}  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must write a trigger, you might also consider the re-parenting of an Opportunity. This is why the Roll-Up Summary field is preferred by many developers. There may be edge cases that generate errors or unexpected results.

```
trigger CountOpportunitiesOnAccount on Opportunity (after insert, after delete, after update){
Set<Id> aId = new Set<Id>();   
if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isDelete || Trigger.isUndelete || Trigger.isUpdate){
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            if(Trigger.newMap.get(opp.Id).AccountID != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).AccountID){
                aId.add(opp.AccountId);
            } 
        }
        else{
            aId.add(opp.AccountId);
        }
    }  
    if(aID != NULL && aID.size() > 0){
        updateAccounts(aId);
    }       
}
if(Trigger.isDelete){
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.old){
        aId.add(opp.AccountId);
    }
    updateAccounts(aId);
}   
private void updateAccounts(Set<Id> accIds){
    List<Account> accs = [select id, Number_Of_Opps__c, (select Id from Opportunities) from Account where Id in :accIds];
    List<Account> liAccToUpdate = new list<Account>();
    //Should be able to handle more than one opportunity/account in the trigger.
    for(Account a : accs){
        //Prevent recursive updating
        if(a.Number_Of_Opps__c != a.Opportunities.size()){
            a.Number_Of_Opps__c = a.Opportunities.size();
            liAccToUpdate.add(a);
        } 
    }
    if(liAccToUpdate != NULL && liAccToUpdate.size() > 0){
        update accs;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void opportunityCount(List<opportunity> oppList) {
    set<id>accountIDs = new set<id>();
    list<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    
    
    for (opportunity eachOppAccId:oppList) {
        accountIDs.add(eachOppAccId.AccountId);
    }
    
    for (Account eachAccount:[select id,No_Of_Opportunities__c, (select id, AccountID from opportunities) from Account where id In:accountIDs]) {
        eachAccount.No_Of_Opportunities__c=eachAccount.opportunities.size();
        accList.add(eachAccount);
    }
    
    update accList;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.